# Flask session behaves erratically

Tags: python, session, flask

My Flask Session behaves in an unpredictable manner. I'm using the same Flask Session settings I did in my previous project, and yet this time it's completely chaotic.

I log in, save the value in `session["user_type"]` to track the account privileges, and then after going to another page with `@admin_required` wrapper sometimes it goes on in a normal way, and sometimes it redirects me back to the login page, because it can't read that `"user_type"` key.

I've read somewhere that it may happen with `"SECRET_KEY"` missing, but as you can see, I have it in my code, so have no idea where the issue might be.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "abcdef"

# Session settings
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = "session"
app.config["SESSION_USE_SIGNER"] = True
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME"] = timedelta(hours=16)
Session(app)

def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_type") != "admin":
            flash(Markup("<strong>Error: admin level required</strong>" +
                         "<br>If you have an admin account, please sign in."),
                  "danger")
            return redirect("/sign-in")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.route("/admin/article/add")
@admin_required
def article_add():
    return render_template("article_add.html")


@app.route("/admin/dashboard")
@admin_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `session.permanent = True`
This just applies your permanent session lifetime.

Comment: I've tried both `app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True` and `session.permanent = True`, the result is the same. I did create a some small workaround by creating a second session, through the separate variable, to store the login data, but then it is gone when the page or browser is closed. But at least the login screen does not pop up every time I move to some login-restricted page during the same browsing session.

Comment: Maybe try not to mix get and post requests too much. I had an issue with sessions, and the only thing I could attribute it to is that.